# Lvalue required

Tags: c, lvalue

I have some problem regarding the following code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{ int a=6,b=2,g;
  a>b?g=a:g=b;
 }
```

this is executing properly without any error. But if seen properly, this should have given a **Lvalue Required** error. **(a>b?g=a:g)** is the actual expression since no parenthesis is being used as **a>b?g=a:(g=b);** and the value **b is being assigned to the constant value obtained after solving the expression on the left of the second assignment (=) operator, which is an error for sure.** Please help on this topic.

Comment: What compiler? GCC 4.6.3 here and it breaks like it should.

Comment: This gives `t.c:4:12: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment` (as expected) when I compile it.

Comment: Note that the expression here is the same as in the duplicate.  Observe that `a>b?g=a:g=b` is treated as `((a > b) ? g = a : g) = b`, and you really can't assign to the result of the ternary operator because it is an r-value, not an l-value.

Answer (score 2):

The result of the conditional operator is never a lvalue in C.

If you didn't get a diagnostic with the statement with the conditional expression, it is not C. Check you are using a C compiler (and not a C++ compiler - the rules for the conditional operator are different in C++) and that the ISO mode is enabled.

Comment: While it's true that the ternary operation would compile in C++, the code itself shouldn't compile in C++ anyway, because `main` returns `void`.

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator is itself an Rvalue. It doesn't exactly do control flow, more gives a value out given a condition.

To fix, try `g = a > b ? a : b`.

Comment: True, but you missed the point. That doesn't answer the question: OP asked why he didn't get an error, not how to fix the error that he didn't get.

Comment: Oh yeah. I just saw the code and assumed it was broken after a skim, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Do not do that:

```
a>b?g=a:g=b;
```

try this:

```
g = (a>b)?a:b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `g=` part to the beginning:

```
g=a>b?a:b;
```

That will do what you want...